# Unable to reference react 'this' from fetch() callbacks inside event handler

Tags: reactjs

Unable to this.setState() with fetch() response

Did fetch() inside form submit event handler, but unable to set the state from the fetch() callbacks

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

```
    ...
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { deviceName: '', devices: [] };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSearchDevice = this.handleSearchDevice.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            devices: this.props.devices
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            devices: nextProps.devices
        });
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({deviceName: event.target.value });
    }
    handleSearchDevice(event) {
        console.log('Searching '+this.state.deviceName)
        event.preventDefault();

        //Get data from API
        const url = 'device/name'
        const data = { deviceName:this.state.deviceName}
        fetch(url, { method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).then(res => {
            res.json().then(function(data) {
                console.log('API Response: '+JSON.stringify(data))
                try {
                    this.setState({devices: data.resp, deviceName: data.deviceName})
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log('catch ' + err.stack)
                    this.callback1(data)
                }
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error)
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('Success:', response)
        });
    }
    callback1(data) {
        this.setState({devices: data.resp, deviceName: data.deviceName})
        console.log(data)
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    }

    ...
```

I expect to set the state from callbacks inside the event handler
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXklk.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have not bound the function `callback1` to `this`. So in your constructor you should bind it the same way you bind your other functions.

An alternative way is to make `callback1` an arrow function instead so that it does not have to be bound. That would look like this:

```
callback1 = () => {
    this.setState({devices: data.resp, deviceName: data.deviceName})
    console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: That worked. Much appreciated @ApplePearPerson for the clear answer

```
res.json().then((data) => {
       console.log('API Response: '+JSON.stringify(data))
       try {
        this.setState({devices: data.resp, deviceName: data.deviceName})
```